# Error while configuring libgraph

Tags: graphics

I have extracted the tar file of `libgraph` from a source and after extracting it, I have used the following command to configure it:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/lib
```

After this command was run, it gave an error configure:

```
error: *** SDL version 1.2.0 not found!
```

Kindly help me.